# Stretch div between header and footer

Tags: css

The task I encountered looks standard: I have a fixed height container and 3 `div`'s inside it. I want the 2nd `div` to be stretched between the top and the bottom `div`'s. When the contents of the 2nd `div` overflows - I would like to show the scroll bars.

I know how to accomplish this task using the `absolute` positioning. A question is: can I do it using the `table` on `div`s?

An additional requirement: if possible, I would like to avoid setting header's height as fixed.

I have tried to code it in my fiddle, but, as you see, [I failed](http://jsfiddle.net/USZXa/).

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.table > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.table > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.center > div {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 700px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table">
     <div>
         <div>XXX</div>
     </div>
     <div class="center">
         <div>
             <div class="content"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <div>YYY</div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to code it in my fiddle, but, as you see, I failed: http://jsfiddle.net/USZXa/

Comment: I'm not sure what "can I do it using the table on divs?" means.

Comment: Sorry for my English, isherfood, I mean I want to use the table created from the divs with "display: table", "display: table-row", "display: table-cell" attributes, you can see it the code I provided.

Comment: Hello! I posted an updated answer to you question two days ago and I wanted to make sure that you had a chance to review it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div>Top Header Block</div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
        </div><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .center -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div>Bottom Footer Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
}
.header, .footer {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
.center {
    height: inherit;
}
.content {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    height: inherit;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Since you are fixing the height of the container, you inherit the height both in the `.center` and the `.content` `<div>`'s.

If you tweak the container height, the center div expands but the header and footer div's stay the same height.

Use `overflow` on the content div to allow for scrolling.

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nae5z/

Comment: Did you measure the resulting height?

Comment: The OP required a fixed height, did not say say that it had to be easy to specify.

Comment: I thought, he wants a fixed height for the whole container, no matter what's the heights of his header and footer. Your solution gives the content this height, but the container's height will be content height + header height + footer height. Well, maybe I misunderstood the OP.

Comment: You can simplify this: Remove the inherited heights and just give the `height: 200px` to the `.content` instead of the `.container`.

Comment: I think that we are solving two slightly different problems and it is good to understand how each works.  Fixing the height of the `.content` div  would also work.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, your solution is really elegant!

Comment: Your very welcome, good luck with the project!  An up vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your way was right, just make a few changes (See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USZXa/40/)):

```
html, body, .container, .table {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#header,#footer {
    height: 1px;
}
```

This should work because tables cells get increased in height if the content needs it.

Just a hint: You may improve the whole thing, for example I would use HTML 5 and the `<header/>` and `<footer/>` elements. But that was not part of your question. Anyway, here is another update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USZXa/69/):

```
 <div>
      <header>
          <div>XXX</div>
      </header>
      <main>
          <div>
              <div class="content"></div>
          </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
          <div>YYY</div>
      </footer>
 </div>
```

With CSS:

```
html, body, body > div {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

body > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

body > div > * {
    display: table-row;
}

body > div > * > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

header, footer {
    height: 1px;
}
```

`main` is very new to HTML 5, just if you're wondering.

Comment: @Kutabeach are you sure you want the header and footer to be scollable? anyway if you want a nice scoll : http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Comment: The advantage of the `table-cell` approach is that you can center the content vertically.

Comment: If you put in enough lines of content in your demo, the content expands but does not trigger the scroll, which is good to be able to do in some cases. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/USZXa/71/

Comment: @Marc: You are absolutely right! I didn't think so far. My solution does not what I wanted to do. Please give me a -1, I cannot terminate my self. ;-)

Comment: Also, look how the background color is behaving.  You could fix that by background-color'ing the child elements instead of the parent container.  No idea about the scrolling.